# How to measure the speed of a website using php?

Tags: php, pagespeed

I have a list of URLs in an array and want to check how long it takes to access each webpage. Can you please tell me if it is possible to find a speed of a webpage using PHP? I would really appreciate it if you can show it to me with an example

Comment: Define what is a "speed of webpage" for you. Maybe grabbing a page using Zend_Http_Client is what you need?

Answer (score 2):

If your web site runs entirely on php, you can measure how long the php script works. If you want to measure the response time of your server you can use firefox or chrome developer menu options which display the total access time to the server.

**To measure the lifetime of a php script:**
The php function microtime() is a handy tool for time profiling.
At the entry of your site add:

```
 $startTime = microtime(true);
 register_shutdown_function('measureTime');

 function measureTime(){
 global $startTime;
     $execTime = microtime(true)-$startTime;
     echo "Script execution time: $execTime seconds.";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for measuring server-side speed would be... capturing time before and after the code, subtracting the values and displaying the result. If there is something even simpler, please, do tell :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the page (either via GET or POST) and time it. This will tell you how long the page takes to load.

Some simple pseudo code:

```
<?php

$lines = file ('url_list.txt');
foreach ($lines as $url)
{
    $start_request = time();
    fetch_webpage ($url);
    $end_request = time ();

    $time_taken = $end_request - $start_request;
}
```

How you implement the `fetch_webpage()` part is up to you. You can [use PHP sockets](http://php.net/fsockopen) or [CURL](http://php.net/curl).

Keep in mind that this will only time the loading time of the original URL. Other resources (that are externally loaded) will not be requested, you need to make sure you do that so your timing will be as accurate as possible.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[xdebug](http://xdebug.org) is a tool to analyze your PHP-code. It supports stack and function traces, profiling information and memory allocation and script execution analysis. You'll exactly see how much time is spent within functions, external calls, ...